# Saving multiple values into an array using sqlite and andorid studio

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

So I followed a tutorial regarding sqlite and android studio and how to save data into a database and being able to view this data later on. The tutorial only showed how to save one value to the database. But how can I save multiple values to this array?

This is the method where the data is added to the array:

```
    private void populateListView() {
    Log.d(TAG, "populateListView: Displaying data in the ListView.");

    Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getData();
    ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
    while(data.moveToNext()){
        listData.add("Id :"+ data.getString(0)+"\n");
        listData.add("Value :"+ data.getString(1)+"\n");
        listData.add("Note :"+ data.getString(2)+"\n");
        listData.add("Category :"+ data.getString(3)+"\n");
        listData.add("Payment :"+ data.getString(4)+"\n\n");

    }
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

As soon as I try to add more than one value to the Listview the app crashes. 
This is my list view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Do I have to change anything here to be able to add muliple values? I'm completly new to android stuido and java, so there might be just one stupid mistake I am not able to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding each column as a new item in the list concatenate all the column values of each row and add it to the list, so each item of the list contains 1 row of the table.
So change your `while` loop to this:

```
String row;
while(data.moveToNext()){
    row = "Id :"+ data.getString(0)+"\n" +
          "Value :"+ data.getString(1)+"\n"+
          "Note :"+ data.getString(2)+"\n"+
          "Category :"+ data.getString(3)+"\n"+
          "Payment :"+ data.getString(4);
    listData.add(row)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! But for some reason the app still crashses when I try to open the listview.